# Simplify .format printing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, format

I'm trying to print out the following:

```
-----------------------------
|             |             |
|             |      P      |
|             |      Y      |
|             |      T      |
|   PYTHON!   |      H      |
|             |      O      |
|             |      N      |
|             |      !      |
|             |             |
-----------------------------
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
|PYTHON!      |      PYTHON!|
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
|             |             |
-----------------------------
```

Here's what I have:

```
rowBorder = '-' * 29
col = '|'
space = ' '
emptyColRow4 = (col + space * 13 + col + space * 13 + col + "\n") * 4
text = 'PYTHON!'
emptyRow = col+space*13+col+space*13+col

print(rowBorder)
print(emptyRow)
for l in text:
    if l != 'H':
        verticalLetter = '{}{}{}'.format(col + space*13 + col + space*6,l,space*6+col)
    else:
        verticalLetter = '{}{:^13}{}{}{}'.format(col,text, col + space*6,l,space*6+col)
    print(verticalLetter)
print(emptyRow)
print(rowBorder)
print(emptyColRow4,end='')
print('{}{:<13}{}{:>13}{}'.format(col,text,col,text,col))
print(emptyColRow4,end='')
print(rowBorder)
```

Is there some way we could embed the *for* loop directly into the *print* statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python supports the concept of format-strings.
A format string such as below allows you to
store data into a string almost as if it were
literal. This is not required to answer your
question but it is nice. A list comprehension
joined by new-lines would be how I would wrap
your loop into a single line. It is my opinion
that this does too much in a single line but
here is a way you could do it.

```
print('\n'.join([f'{col}{text if l == "H" else space:^13}{col}{space*6}{l}{space*6+col}' for l in text]))
```

Comment: I notice that everything following the 'f' is in a quote.  Can I put that in a string and do  f string for l in text? but very cool as it is

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... f'{[i for i in text]}' is valid.
For more information you can read on generator expressions, dictionary expressions, set comprehensions.
[here](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html)

Comment: @DCR you can read about f-strings here: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 3 ['f-strings'](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals).
Simplified? Well, may be.

```
text = 'PYTHON!'
w = len(text) * 2
rowBorder = ' ' + '-' * (w * 2 + 1)
col = '|'
fill = ' ' * w
print(rowBorder)
for i in range(0, len(text)+2):
    lcol = fill
    rcol = lcol
    if i == len(text)//2:
        hw = (w - len(text))//2
        lcol = f"{fill[:hw]}{text}{fill[:hw]} "
    if i >= 1 and i <= len(text):
        rcol = f"{fill[:w//2]}{text[i-1]}{fill[:w//2-1]}"
    print(f"|{lcol}|{rcol}|")

print(rowBorder)

for i in range(0, len(text)+2):
    lcol = fill
    rcol = lcol
    if i == len(text)//2:
        rcol = f"{text: >{w}}"
        lcol = f"{text: <{w}}"
    print(f"|{lcol}|{rcol}|")

print(rowBorder)
```

if `text='NOT SIMPLE!'`

```
 ---------------------------------------------
|                      |                      |
|                      |           N          |
|                      |           O          |
|                      |           T          |
|                      |                      |
|     NOT SIMPLE!      |           S          |
|                      |           I          |
|                      |           M          |
|                      |           P          |
|                      |           L          |
|                      |           E          |
|                      |           !          |
|                      |                      |
 ---------------------------------------------
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|NOT SIMPLE!           |           NOT SIMPLE!|
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
|                      |                      |
 ---------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored a little bit to reduce the number of *print* statements using [f-strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_(programming_language)#Expressions) and also used an inline for the conditional statements.

```
rowBorder, col, space = '-' * 29, '|', ' '
emptyColRow4 = (col + space * 13 + col + space * 13 + col + "\n") * 4
text = 'PYTHON!'
emptyRow = col + space*13 + col + space*13 + col

print(f"{rowBorder}\n{emptyRow}")
for l in text:
    print('{}{}{}'.format(col + space*13 + col + space*6, l, space*6 + col) if l != 'H' else '{}{:^13}{}{}{}'.format(col, text, col + space*6, l, space*6 + col))
print(f"{emptyRow}\n{rowBorder}")
print(emptyColRow4, end='')
print('{}{:<13}{}{:>13}{}'.format(col, text, col, text, col))
print(emptyColRow4, end='')
print(rowBorder)
```